# How to collect the static files for flask admin when using pyinstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller, flask-admin

I have a flask project that uses flask admin.

I am packaging it using pyinstaller. I am doing the following to create my pyinstaller script

```
mkdir ./src/static
cp -r ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flasgger/ui2/templates/. ./src/templates
cp -r ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_admin/templates/. ./src/templates
cp -r ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flasgger/ui2/static/. ./src/static
cp -r ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_admin/static/. ./src/static
pyinstaller \
    --onefile \
    --add-data "./src/templates:templates" \
    --add-data "./src/static:static" \
    --add-data "./src/swagger:swagger" \
    --paths ".:./src/:./test:./venv" \
    ./src/app.py
```

my `app.py` does the following

```
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        template_folder = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'templates')
        static_folder = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'static')
        app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_folder, static_folder=static_folder)
    else:
        app = Flask(__name__)
```

I see that the `flasgger` view and its static files are being served okay. However `flask_admin` static files are not getting served and are giving a 404 error.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

When pyinstaller builds the application, It generally includes the files that are actually called.

In flask_admin, the static files are accessed from HTML file, in which pyinstaller recognize static files as unused file and it does not include it in the build file.

In such cases, you cannot import packages from site-packages.

you have to place the flask_admin package from where you run the application and import flask_admin from local.

For example:
consider this app structure

```
project
   |--- app
         |--- __init__.py
         |--- ... (other files)
   |--- flask_admin
   |--- run.py
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    admin = Admin(app)
    ...
    ...
    return app
```

**run.py**

```
from app import creare_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

here:

- The flask_admin should not be installed in the environment.
- The flask_admin package should be placed where you run the app. (download flask_admin from git).
- The entire flask_admin package should also be added while building the application using **pyinstaller**.

sample command :

> pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "/dir/app;app/" **--add-data "/dir/flask_admin;flask_admin/"** run.py

---

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/ajeeth-b/Billing-Software)